# How to put links of Stack Overflow answers by me and questions asked by me on the Windows Live site

Tags: discussion

I have been spending some time in Stack Overflow and enjoy researching and answering questions rather than updating my Windows live [blog](http://ashishrocks.spaces.live.com/) regularly. I heard Joel Spolsky somewhere that you can think of each of your contributions in Stack Overflow as a blog post if you don't have a blog.

Well, is it possible to have links of the questions I asked and the questions I answered in Stack Overflow in my Windows live site? Or is there any alternative? I already have the Stack Overflow flair in my Windows Live site (which I have to manually update :-( ) and Facebook profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's your feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/255562). Integrating that into a blog is left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: +1, Thank you for the quick response. I realized It was "Feed" I was asking for. The question should have been shorter. :-)